# Function that accepts any numeric type in C

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am trying to build a program in C, which might receive any type of numeric array and a number to search in array, and will return its location.
Currently I get and error of " error: invalid use of void expression" for line#3 in the `func` function.
Is the way I am trying to solve the issue even relevant? If not what should be the solution as I want to make as generic as possible?

The code is as follows:

```
void func(int,void*,double,int);
int main(){
        /* arrays and numbers to search in each array*/
        int arrInt[]={3,4,5,15,6,24,7,13,12};
        double arrD[]={1.1,1.4,1.5,2.2,7.6,10.2};
        long arrL[]={10,20,30,40,50,60};
        int i2s=7;
        double d2s=7.6;
        long l2s=40;

        func(sizeof(int*),arrInt,i2s,9);
        func(sizeof(double*),arrD,d2s,6);
        func(sizeof(long*),arrL,l2s,6);

}

void func(int size,void *arr,double num,int arrSize){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++){
                if((double*)*arr==num)
                        return i+1;
                arr=arr+size;
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: `*(double*)arr`

Comment: A void function returning something...

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do, and what you are actually doing makes no sense. Casting an unknown pointer to `double*` won't magically convert the pointed-to number to `double`. There are other flaws but this one is most serious. You need a different approach.

Comment: Why `void*`? Can't you pass through the actual type or is this a constraint you're not describing?

Comment: For inspiration, study how standard functions bsearch and qsort work. bsearch is very similar to what you need, the only difference is that it searches in a sirted array. Your case is simpler.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [type-generic macros](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.1.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing `void*` in the condition below triggers the error:

```
 if((double*)*arr==num)
```

Also, doing pointer arithmetic on `void*` is not standard.

Even if you fix the syntax to dereference *after* pointer conversion, the comparison would fail unless you actually pass an array of `double`s, so you need to change the approach.

You could fix the problem by passing a pointer to the search item, and doing the comparison using `memcmp`:

```
int func(size_t size, void *arr, void* pnum, size_t arrSize) {
    for (int i=0 ; i != arrSize ; i++, arr = ((char*)arr)+size ) {
        if(memcmp(arr, pnum, size)==0)
                return i+1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that now you need an address-of operator `&` in the call, i.e.

```
int x = func(sizeof(int), arrInt, &i2s, 9);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/baTEIf)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is here:

```
(double*)*arr
```

You're attempting to dereference a `void *` which is not allowed.  You want to cast that pointer to a particular type and *then* dereference:

```
*(double *)arr
```

However, this still won't do what you want.  For types other than `double`, you'll be attempting to read a number of bytes as if they are a `double`.  Different types have different representations, so you can't take an address containing an `int`, tell the compiler to read it as a `double`, and expect to get anything meaningful out.

For this to work, you would need to pass the actual type to the function (or a value specifying a type).  Types can't be passed in C, so you would need a flag:

```
enum searchTypes {
    INT,
    LONG,
    DOUBLE
};

void func(int type, void *arr, double num, int arrSize){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<arrSize; i++){
                double val = 0;
                switch (type) {
                case INT: 
                    val = ((int *)arr)[i];
                    break;
                case LONG: 
                    val = ((long *)arr)[i];
                    break;
                case DOUBLE: 
                    val = ((double *)arr)[i];
                    break;
                }
                if (val==num) {
                        return i+1;
                }
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
func(INT,arrInt,i2s,9);
func(DOUBLE,arrD,d2s,6);
func(LONG,arrL,l2s,6);
```